# How to change MFC application UI

Tags: windows, user-interface, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I have implemented an windows application using Visual studio 2008 and for front end I used MFC Controls.
I need to change look and feel of application. Here is Ui sample image of old and new look.
[image: Top image is my old UI and bottom image is what i want to implement.]

Can anybody suggest me how it can be done in visual studio or should I use some other tool.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know of a native MFC way of this, but there are third-party skin/themes frameworks like [BCGSoft](http://www.bcgsoft.com/featuretour/tour88.htm) or [CodeJock Skin Framework](http://www.codejock.com/products/skinframework/?2yn6s14z=zsp)

Comment: MFC follows whatever the user of your software selected as their standard theme. Why do you think the user will like your choice better than theirs?

Comment: @Mayank Prabhakar You can handle the OnCtlColor of the CDialog for the background color. You can change the Font (which will be applied to all child controls) from the dialog editor. You can make the CTabCtrl owner drawn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3139sdy.aspx; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7eax1x4(v=vs.120).aspx; http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/controls/tabcontrols/article.php/c2237/Implementing-an-owner-drawn-Tab-Control.htm

Comment: See my comments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30052718/cmfcmenubutton-does-not-respect-dark-color-scheme#comment50704615_30052718 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673801/how-to-skin-mfc-main-menu#comment62753981_11673801 ; my answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/31348831/383779 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/22875542/383779

Comment: BTW, I succeeded once to skin an application to make it seem like the Windows High Contrast scheme deriving my own class from a `CMFCVisualManager` descendent class

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 3 ways:

1. Implement it yourself
2. Use an external library like [Codejock](http://www.codejock.com)
3. Adding a manifest file to your project

Using a manifest file will give you the look and feel of the OS your app is running on.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite some needed methods of default CMFCVisualManger by creating your own class.

Then it's up to you how you want to design it.